# Invite your friends via email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hey, im not sure if theres a technical 'term' for this, but on some social networking sites there is a 'invite your friends' page, which allows you to type your email address, and password, and send a generic invite email to everyone in the users contacts list. can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial / old forum post that might help me learn how to do this please?

i am using asp.net.

Comment: You can loop a cycle and send a email to each of the recipients (that are placed inside an array)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use SmtpClient to send your emails, and have a template of the email you want to send.  don't know what else can be told about it.

Comment: can u help me with this?? http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/ how to use this api??

Answer (score 0):

Create a page with multiple text boxes and generic invite message text box.

On Button click do this

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, 
  txtInvite.Text); //You can interate through all text boses to reach to a final TO list
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(txtSMTPServer.Text);
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = 
  new System.Net.NetworkCredential(<GetUserFromConfig>, <GetPasswordFromConfig>);
emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
emailClient.Send(message);
```

There are different variants here, like Authentication, SMTP settings etc. For that, you will have to understand them first, so here are two links which should help you out

[ASP.Net Offical Site](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-aspnet-to-send-email-from-a-web-site)

[Tutorial](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-auth-aspnet2-csharp.aspx)

Comment: actually i wanted to ask how do i retrieve the contact list of the users email id??

Answer (score 0):

Find here : [How-to Import contacts from hotmail, live, gmail, yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660160/import-contacts-from-hotmai-live-gmail-yahoo)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/ how do i use this api in my website??

Comment: @Monodeep : read this one I think u have to use individual techniques for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002967/c-library-that-extracts-gmail-yahoomail-and-aol-contacts

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/ this project also have console example application you can use in webform application also...